# Can I do an API call when the App is in the background, and this would trigger a Local Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to create a local notification with the following requirements:

- The user selects what time of the day he would like to receive the notification for example : 
  between 8:00 AM and 9:00 AM
- The message contained in the notification requires calling an API to get and updated content.

I was able to create the Local Notification, but my problem is once my app is in the background, the API call is not made anymore and the Notifications stop too

I understand that I should use the Background Fetch, but according to my research I cannot use Background Fetch for what I want to do.

In my case I would need to make an API Call every 5 minutes, while my App is in the background

Comment: With your specific requirements, the only way to accomplish something similar would be a server-initiated push notification. If your intent is just to make sure that the user gets data periodically, background fetch is probably the preferred approach, though you don't have the level of control that you're looking for.

Comment: @Rob : What if I use a custom NSTimeInterval instead of `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum`.
 For example :
`UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(600.0)`

Comment: That's a minimum, not a maximum. That's intended to say "hey, Apple, don't bother checking more frequently than _x,_ because my server only updates itself with that frequency, anyway." In terms of the frequency that the OS will actually perform background fetch, it's determined by a poorly documented algorithm that factors in app usage pattern as well as the state of the device (wifi v cellular, charging v non-charging, etc.). You have very little control over the specifics. But if app is used a lot and device is charging and on wifi, background fetch will run with greater frequency.